# Is it possible to type text by triggering keypress events via javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to write text where the cursor is, one way to do that I figure is to trigger keyboard event. However, despite what I do it doesn't seem to actually cause text to be written.

```
setTimeout(function(){
var evt = document.createEvent('Event');
evt.initEvent('keydown', true, true);
evt.view = window;
evt.altKey = false;
evt.ctrlKey = false;
evt.shiftKey = false;
evt.metaKey = false;
evt.keyCode = 0;
evt.charCode = 113;

document.activeElement.dispatchEvent(evt);
}, 2000);
```

Or

```
setTimeout(function () {
    var e = new KeyboardEvent("keypress", { bubbles: true, cancelable: true, key: "Q", char: "Q", shiftKey: true });
    document.activeElement.dispatchEvent(e);
}, 2000);
```

Comment: You can just edit the text value of a form, right? Otherwise, wouldn't that be insecure? Like it can just control the keyboard?

Comment: I can't edit the value, I need to be able to type via js

Comment: `evt.charCode` should be an integer, not a string.

Comment: also how are you going to be triggering this...

Comment: @MuhammadUmer it may help to provide a succinct explanation of *why* you can’t edit the value of the field (as generally-accepted best practices would dictate)

Comment: @MichaelMano The code triggers it using `setTimeout`

Comment: Do you want to trigger keypress events or do you just need a value entered into a input the mouse is over? - just trying to come up with the best solution.

Comment: need a value entered into a input programmatically

Comment: Can't edit the value because it's a fake editor not textarea

Comment: it seems to me that you can't programmatically fire keyboard event and have text show up, can't find source though, you can fire keyboard event and have event handlers trigger

Comment: I found something which seems to do the trick

Comment: You can automatically fire a keyboard event, but is has to be dispatched from a node that exists. A better solution would be to just use a function *(the same one that you use on the listener)* and call it when you need to, unless you need to specifically use the Event Object.

Answer (score 1):

```
function addText(text, target  = document.activeElement) {
    text = text || '';
    if (document.selection) {      // IE
      target.focus();
      var sel = document.selection.createRange();
      sel.text = text;
    } else if (this.selectionStart || this.selectionStart === 0) { // Others
      var startPos = target.selectionStart;
      var endPos = target.selectionEnd;
      target.value = target.value.substring(0, startPos) + text + target.value.substring(endPos, this.value.length);
      target.selectionStart = startPos + text.length;
      target.selectionEnd = startPos + text.length;
    } else {
      target.value += text;
    }
};
```

or

```
const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();

function dispatchPaste(text, target = document.activeElement) {
    // this may be 'text/html' if it's required
    dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', text);
  
    target.dispatchEvent(
      new ClipboardEvent('paste', {
        clipboardData: dataTransfer,
  
        // need these for the event to reach Draft paste handler
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true
      })
    );
  
    // clear DataTransfer Data
    dataTransfer.clearData();
  }
```

this also works

```
document.execCommand('insertText', false, 'text to enter')
```